# How to use the CS:GO sharing code

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In the 'Watch' tab there is a match sharing code for your last games. If i want to share a demo to my friends, what should they do to see it? How to use the sharing code? Is there a special command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a Copy Link near that code. If you click it you should get a URL like this one: steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_download_match%20CSGO-Y4DVh-amkvh-OyBrh-SyMHN-2SvPB

If you put that in a browser tab it will tell CS:GO to launch via steam and then watch the match.. The code at the end of the URL is the id of the match.